# Android open database if it's not open already

Tags: android

Hi I am using the standard DabAdapter open(). When I am doing that how can I check if it's already open. As I am getting few errors and origin of those errors is

```
  database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
```

Complete code is

```
public DbAdapter open() throws SQLException {
              dbHelper = new DbOpenHelper(this.context);
              database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
              return this;
       }
```

Comment: Of what type are those "few errors" you're getting: Compile time or runtime? If the latter, please post the stacktrace(s). In both cases, include the exact error messages.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (database.isOpen()) { .... }
```

Comment: so if(!database.isOpen()) { database = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase(); return this; } else { return database; } ....... is this right?

Comment: no, you have to return a DbAdapter. The isOpen() part is correct, though.

Comment: @Bondax can provide a little bit more code/explanation - it'll be cool.